# Change the spark's context web ui url in kubernetes for a url accessible from outside the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, spark-ui

Hell everyone, I have a problem with Apache Spark (version 3.3.1) on `k8s`.

In short:
When I run the statement

```py
print(sc.uiWebUrl)
```

within a pod, I would get a `URL` that is accessible from outside the `k8s` cluster.
Something like:

```
http://{{my-ingress-host}}
```

Long story:
I want to create a workspace for Apache Spark on `k8s`, where the driver's pod, is the **workspace** that I work on. I want to let the client run Apache Spark either with `pyspark-shell` or with the `pyspark` python library.

In either way, I want that the UI's web url would be a one that is accessible from the outside world (outside the `k8s` cluster).
Why? Because of `UX`, I want to make my client's life easier.

Because I run on `k8s`, part of the configuration of my Apache Spark program is:

```
spark.driver.host={{driver-service}}.{{drivers-namespace}}.svc.cluster.local
spark.driver.bindAddress=0.0.0.0
```

Because of that, the output of this code:

```py
print(sc.webUiUrl)
```

Would be:

```
http://{{driver-service}}.{{drivers-namespace}}.svc.cluster.local:4040
```

Also in the pyspark-shell, the same address would be displayed.

So my question is, is there a way to change the ui web url's host to a host that I have defined in my `ingress` to make my client's life easier?
So the new output would be:

```
http://{{my-defined-host}}
```

Other points I want to make sure to adjust the solution as much as possible:

- I don't have a `nginx` ingress in my k8s cluster. Maybe I have a `HAPROXY` ingress. But I would want to be coupled to my ingress implementation as **least** as possiable.
- I would prefer that the client would need to configure Apache Spark as **least** as possible.
- I would prefer that the ui web url of the Spark's context would be set when creating the context, meaning before the `pyspark-shell` displays the welcome screen.
- I have tried messing with the `ui.proxy` configurations, and it haven't helped. And sometimes made things worst.

Thanks ahead for everyone, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your web UI's host to a host that you want by setting the [`SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/configuration.html#environment-variables) environment variable. This needs to be done on the driver, since the web UI runs on the driver.

To set the port for the web UI, you can do that using the [`spark.ui.port`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/configuration.html#spark-ui) config parameter.

So putting both together using `spark-submit` for example, makes something like the following:

```
bin/spark-submit \
   --class ... \
   --master k8s://... \
   ....
   ....
   ....
   --conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=YOUR_VALUE_HERE
   --conf spark.ui.port=YOUR_WANTED_PORT_HERE
   ...
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but it would still display the port of the spark ui. Because I am using k8s, I can't change the port of the host. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I've added that info to my answer, is that what you need?

Comment: It's a good solution.

But I have another challenge, if I have multiple spark programs on the same workspace, each would obtain different port. And in `k8s`, I am allowed to hold only **one** port for each host in my `Ingress`.
Do you have a solution for this?
I am sorry for the confusion and complications, maybe this question deserves to be under it's own section.

Comment: Happy to be of help! I would suggest to open up a different question post for this, as this is indeed diverges from your original question. If you feel your original question has been answered, don't hesitate to accept my answer here.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I would do as you suggested.